# PySide, Docking windows to taskbar

Tags: python, qt, pyside, taskbar, qtgui

I am writing a program with PySide and Python 2.7.

```
class SystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):

        QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon.__init__(self, parent)

        self.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon("myIcon.ico"))

        self.iconMenu = QtGui.QMenu(parent)
        appcalc = self.iconMenu.addAction("ShowWindow")
        appexit = self.iconMenu.addAction("Exit")
        self.setContextMenu(self.iconMenu)

        self.connect(appcalc, QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'),self.appCalc)
        self.connect(appexit,QtCore.SIGNAL('triggered()'),self.appExit)

        self.show()
```

This code display a working taskbar icon with an iconMenu. Now when i click on "show window" I want to load a widget/windows docked to the taskbar at the same location of the icon.

If i would use geometry this would never work because some people have taskbar on top, or on the side of the screen.

How to have a docked window / widget to the taskbar with PySide?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use a combination of [QDesktopWidget.availableGeometry()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html#availableGeometry) and [QDesktopWidget.screenGeometry()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdesktopwidget.html#screenGeometry) to work out the size of the taskbar and its orientation:

```
>>> d = qApp.desktop()
>>> d.screenGeometry()
PySide.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1600, 900)
>>>>
>>> d.availableGeometry() # taskbar at top
PySide.QtCore.QRect(0, 36, 1600, 864)
>>> d.availableGeometry() # taskbar on left
PySide.QtCore.QRect(36, 0, 1564, 900)
>>>
>>> d.availableGeometry() # taskbar at bottom
PySide.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1600, 864)
>>> d.availableGeometry() # taskbar on right
PySide.QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1564, 900)
```

As you can see, if `x()` or `y()` are non-zero, the taskbar is at the top or on the left; otherwise, if the `width()` or `height()` are less than the screen values, the taskbar is at the bottom or on the right (and if none of the above is true, there is no taskbar).

With that in hand, you can then use [QSystemTrayIcon.geometry()](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsystemtrayicon.html#geometry) to calculate the position of your window relative to the taskbar.

**PS**:

Some window managers have the concept of a margin where windows can't be placed when initially positioned, or when they are maximised. This margin is often set to one or two pixels so that the edge of the desktop is always accessible to the mouse.

So, depending on the target platform, you might need to take this into account when calculating the taskbar size and orientation.

Comment: Hi, thanks that seems a good idea, i'll try to understand it as i am a complete noob with gui and qt. My plan is to make it crossplatform. I will test your idea today